# How to implement a navigation breadcrumb in VS lightswitch html

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

Dears,

Has anyone attempted to implement a breadcrumb for navigation in VS lightswitch? Something like this:

[image]

Such that the user can see the path that led him/her to to the current screen and can navigate back to any screen s/he wants with a click.

Comment: you can navigate back to the last screen by adding a custom button, and on the execute code, add myapp.cancelChanges(); that is if the user has made no changes, alternatively adding your own validation/code and using myapp.commitChanges() will also have the save effect, and the user will end up on the previous screen.

Comment: Thanks for your tip bro, there is a method called `myapp.navigateBack()` which returns back to the previous screen after prompting the user to save his/her changes if any. But I need the button that calls navigateBack to actually display the name of the previous screen too, like a proper breadcrumb